# Magento offline custom Payment method with drop down list

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, magento-2.1.4

I started working on magento2 since 2 months, i have payment method which was working before and suddenly it stopped. i could not able to figure out the problem.

Please find the zip file.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=12IpO3fh-8MfJnMTwHlz26vY7puy5biEg

I tried to copy the module and used in new installed magento but in front-end it displayed the drop down list but order is not getting completed.

[image]

---

This is screen shot of back end which is not Listing out the drop down list. 
When I tried place order from magento backed, it is not saving the "XYZ" selected value in Database.

[image: Back end does't display drop down values]

---

1. my registration.php  file at : `\app\code\K2B\PickPay`

   > \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
   >        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
   >        'K2B_PickPay',
   >   **DIR** );

---

2. File Pickpay.php at : `\app\code\K2B\PickPay\Block\Form`

   > ```
   > <?php
   >
   > namespace K2B\PickPay\Block\Form;
   >
   > class Pickpay extends \Magento\Payment\Block\Form
   > {
   >     /**
   >      * Checkmo template
   >      *
   >      * @var string
   >      */
   >     protected $_template = 'K2B_PickPay::form/pickpay.phtml';
   > }
   > ```
3. File Pickpay.php at  : `\app\code\K2B\PickPay\Block\Info`

   > ```
   >    <?php
   > namespace K2B\PickPay\Block\Info;
   >
   > class Pickpay extends \Magento\Payment\Block\Info
   > {
   >     /**
   >      * @var string
   >      */
   >     protected $_template = 'K2B_PickPay::info/pickpay.phtml';
   >
   >     /**
   >      * @return string
   >      */
   >     public function toPdf()
   >     {
   >         $this->setTemplate('K2B_PickPay::info/pdf/pickpay.phtml');
   >         return $this->toHtml();
   >     }
   > }?>
   > ```
4. Model pickpay.php in `\app\code\K2B\PickPay\Model`

   '

   - Pay In Store payment method model
     */
     class Pickpay extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod
     {
     const PAYMENT_METHOD_PICKPAY_CODE = 'pickpay';
     /**

     - Payment code
       *
     - @var string
       */
       protected $_code = self::PAYMENT_METHOD_PICKPAY_CODE;
       /**
     - Availability option
       *
     - @var bool
       */
       protected $_isOffline = true;
       /**
     - @var string
       */
       protected $_formBlockType = 'K2B\PickPay\Block\Form\Pickpay'; 
       /**
     - @var string
       */
       protected $_infoBlockType = 'K2B\PickPay\Block\Info\Pickpay';
       /**
     - Assign data to info model instance
       *
     - @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject|mixed $data
     - @return $this
     - @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
       */
       public function assignData(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $data)
       {
       $additionalData = $data->getData(PaymentInterface::KEY_ADDITIONAL_DATA);
       if (!is_object($additionalData)) {
       $additionalData = new DataObject($additionalData ?: []);
       }

       /*$myfile = fopen("./var/log/pickpay.txt", "a");
       $txt = "getPickpayLocation:".$additionalData->getPickpayLocation();
       fwrite($myfile, "\n". $txt);
       fclose($myfile);*/
       $this->getInfoInstance()
       ->setPickpayLocation($additionalData->getPickpayLocation());
       return $this;
       }
       }'
5. File UpgradeSchema.php in **`\app\code\K2B\PickPay\Setup`**

   > namespace K2B\PickPay\Setup;
   >
   > use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface; use
   >   Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface; use
   >   Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
   >
   > class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface {
   >       /**
   >        * {@inheritdoc}
   >        */
   >       public function upgrade(
   >           SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
   >           ModuleContextInterface $context
   >       ) {
   >           $installer = $setup;
   >
   > ```
   >     $installer->startSetup();       
   >     if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.1', '<')) {          
   >       $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
   >             $installer->getTable('quote_payment'),
   >             'pickpay_location',
   >             [
   >                 'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
   >                 'length' => 255,
   >                 'comment' => 'Pay and Pick Store Location'
   >             ]
   >         );
   >       $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
   >             $installer->getTable('sales_order_payment'),
   >             'pickpay_location',
   >             [
   >                 'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
   >                 'length' => 255,
   >                 'comment' => 'Pay and Pick Store Location'
   >             ]
   >         );
   >     }
   >
   >     $installer->endSetup();
   > } }
   > ```

Comment: Please let me know if you need more details. Thanks in advance. Sorry, i was not able to put the code in correct format.

Comment: Please upload module zip then anyone can get more idea

Comment: Thanks - Yogesh, https://drive.google.com/open?id=12IpO3fh-8MfJnMTwHlz26vY7puy5biEg

Comment: any one got change to review ?

Comment: As you said `When i tried place order from magento backed, it is not saving the "XYZ" selected value in Database`, that's mean the module is working on frontend?

Comment: module is working in front end it displays dropdown menu. but it is not completing the process of order placement. it will takes long time and redirects to cart page with items listed in cart.  [link] (http://www.alaincooponline.com/checkout/cart/)

Comment: @Keyur Shah can u please check this Question