# Magento ver. 2.1.4 : How to Install a magento Theme

Tags: magento-2.1, theme, installation

I am trying to install the new theme in my Magento store.

I could not do it correctly.

I use Magento Ver. 2.1.4, I was able to do with the fresh installation of Magento but not able to update the theme in existing Magento store.

after my installation all my Front end design is Falling apart. Please suggest me best practice to install new theme. I would like to try that.

Comment: what issues you faced , any error logs that you can share, otherwise there are many post and external links on the same

Comment: my Front end design is Falling apart. Please suggest me best practice to install new theme. I would like to try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) To install new theme, if you don't have theme files then follow their commands to first download theme into your project.

2) If you have theme files put it into your project and after that run below commands in magento2 root directory :

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

After that you can see theme in magento admin panel in `content -> configuration` , from there you can set theme for your store frontend.

Comment: Thank you very much, i will try this. I have installed a new Magento store with Luma theme. every thing works fine but. it is not able to create or sign in user. I am following above mentioned CLI Commands. will this works.?

Comment: While signup/signin, check console, if there is any error?

Comment: Thanks, Can u please check this module. its custom Payment module with drop-down list. [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12IpO3fh-8MfJnMTwHlz26vY7puy5biEg/view)

Comment: Are you facing any error in custom payment module? please create a new question, mention what are you trying to achieve and what error you are facing.

Comment: I have created a new question -[Please find it here] (https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225350/magento-offline-custom-payment-method-with-drop-down-list)