# Mganeto2: CLI commands dealing with languages

Tags: magento2, command-line, language-package

In My Store I am using two languages en_US and ar_SA.

But, unknowingly I ran this command

> **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy es_MX.**

Something like this, other language which I was not using in my store at all.

Please help me understand what will be the consequences of this and how can I revert this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento has below command to deploy the static content for your store which includes the files like `css` file `js` file you `fonts` your `traslation.json` file `images`**(other than the product & catalog images)** & the `html` templates file that are needed in the view structures & used with the `KOjs`at your checkout page. It also produces the separate css & js files written specifically for the modules

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Now at the time of deployment when you want that a specific theme should be get deployed then we can use below command

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme {Vendor}/{theme_name}

& if you are having store with Multiple languages & you wanted to deploy specific store's content in specific language you can use the below command

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US

It will simply deploys the static content for your store in specific language you have used at below location you can find it.

> magento_root\pub\static\frontend{vendor}{theme_name}\en_US{the language code for your store you have used at time of deployment}

Now if you don't want your store in this language or you want to remove these deployed content you can simply run the below commands to revert your store

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy [your_language_code like en_US]
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

Here your store is again available in your chosen language just refresh the front-end page

> Note:Always run these commands from **Magento_root directory**
> (Directory inwhich your **Magento is installed**)

Comment: Can u Please check another question i have posted [here is the Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225350/magento-offline-custom-payment-method-with-drop-down-list) I have given entire module. please download so you will  get good idea.

Comment: If my answer Helped you please do upvote also with accepting it so that it can help others as well.

Comment: Can U please check this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225832/magento2-custom-payment-module-with-drop-down-list-is-not-working)