# Magento2 : How to check errors in magento store

Tags: magento2, orders, error-log, place-order, system.log

In my store when I try to place order, it is not completing order placing process instead it is coming back to Shopping cart page with All products listed.

[image]

Server is very slow stated by the google chrome in Console.

I tried to Check the errors using inspect element. But I could not recognise the errors.

than I checked the error logs in **{Magento root folder}/Var/log/**

> Exception.log
>
> Debug.Log
>
> System.log

After I tested the Payment When I check the Logs, I could not find any entries in **Exceptions.log & Debug.log**. New lines were found in the **System.log** which looks like this below.

[image]

I was not able to understand anything out of it.

Please help me to understand what might be the problem of my store not able to place the order.

Comment: Take a look inside your webserver logs : Apache / Nginx. Also run your store in HTTPS.

Comment: do you have any custom extensions installed recently? probably related to seo, checkout or email?

Comment: Yes this is related to my custom payment method with drop-down list. [Module](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12IpO3fh-8MfJnMTwHlz26vY7puy5biEg).Please let me know what is the problem with the module. [Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225350/magento-offline-custom-payment-method-with-drop-down-list)