# Magento 2 : how to convert my Domain Http:// to Https://

Tags: magento2, url, ssl, multidomain

Till now I was using http:// in my domain, how can I move my domain from Http:// to https://

Do i have to buy a SSL Certificate. my domain was registered through Godaddy.

if i change Following in Magento Admin.

> ```
> Store-> Configuration-> General-> Web 
> - Base URl
> - Base link Url
> ```

Please let me know how to Use SSL Certificate to assign to this Domain.

I have Changed the mu Domain url with http to https.

[image: screenshot]

After changing it Google chrome is not allow me to that Site As it is Not Secure.

Now, I need to add the SSL certificate to my Domain url. As i said earlier.

please let me know the steps for assigning SSL to Domain

Comment: Enabling SSL requires setting Magento app for https, changes in server configuration and a certificate. There are different ways to get a certificate, but first, could you elaborate a bit more on your server setup? Web hotel? Ubuntu? Apache? Nginx? Cloud? Do you have shell-access as root user?

Comment: Reference Link: https://in.godaddy.com/help/install-ssl-certificates-16623

Comment: This is free website that install SSL. https://www.ssl.support

Comment: Thank you @Sourav. I have another question posted [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225350/magento-offline-custom-payment-method-with-drop-down-list). having a issue with custom Payment method, Can u Please help me.

Comment: can you check my answer so other developers also get help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to purchase SSL certificate. There are different vendors provide this SSL service, then you need to generate CSR for your domain and generate public and private key to install SSL successfully for the domain on your server.
Then you need to configure https://yourdomain.com on the secure base url.

Also you need to make configure redirection from http://yourdomain.com to https://www.yourdomain.com

Comment: Can u please list any guide for the CSR generation process related to Godaddy service provider cause my domain is registered with them only. Thanks !

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-commercial-certificate-authority you can take assistance from this link, also godaddy site to have blog for this, right now i am travelling, not on my desk. So only this i can assist you right now. Also did you purchased SSL certificate? There customer support can also guide you. Thanks

Comment: There are freely available certificates as well. Search for lets encrypt and you will find a certificate that doesn't cost.

Answer (score 0):

[GoDaddy SSL Certificates Help](https://in.godaddy.com/help/install-ssl-certificates-16623)

[This is free website that install SSL]
https://www.ssl.support/